# Shuffle/Sorting fails in a map-reduce job

Tags: hadoop, parallel-processing, mapreduce

In my map-reduce job, when I set the number of reducers to 0, the program proceeds to the end successfully in less than 5 mins. However, when I set the number of reducers to something rather than 0 (between 1-40) and even do not specify a reducer class, it proceeds very slowly with many failed tasks and suddenly fails with the following error message. As I do not specify the reducer class, the only thing that can cause this error is sorting the mappers' output. The mapper produces around 27,000 different keys. What is the problem here? There isn't any thing in the log file that can help either. The only conjecture I have is large number of keys cause this problem. How can I solve this problem?

```
  13/10/28 13:06:40 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 70% reduce 18%
  13/10/28 13:07:13 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201310101346_0661_m_000052_2, Status : FAILED
  Task attempt_201310101346_0661_m_000052_2 failed to report status for 600 seconds. Killing!
  13/10/28 13:07:19 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201310101346_0661_m_000059_2, Status : FAILED
  Task attempt_201310101346_0661_m_000059_2 failed to report status for 600 seconds. Killing!
  13/10/28 13:07:23 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 70% reduce 19%
  13/10/28 13:07:24 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201310101346_0661_m_000060_2, Status : FAILED
 Task attempt_201310101346_0661_m_000060_2 failed to report status for 600 seconds. Killing!
 13/10/28 13:07:26 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 70% reduce 20%
 13/10/28 13:07:47 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 71% reduce 20%
 13/10/28 13:07:54 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201310101346_0661_m_000061_2, Status : FAILED
 Task attempt_201310101346_0661_m_000061_2 failed to report status for 600 seconds. Killing!
 13/10/28 13:08:22 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201310101346_0661_m_000062_2, Status : FAILED
 Task attempt_201310101346_0661_m_000062_2 failed to report status for 600 seconds. Killing!
 13/10/28 13:09:03 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 72% reduce 20%
 13/10/28 13:09:15 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201310101346_0661_m_000063_2, Status : FAILED
 Task attempt_201310101346_0661_m_000063_2 failed to report status for 600 seconds. Killing!
13/10/28 13:09:18 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201310101346_0661_m_000066_2, Status : FAILED
 Task attempt_201310101346_0661_m_000066_2 failed to report status for 600 seconds. Killing!
13/10/28 13:09:20 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201310101346_0661_m_000068_2,     Status : FAILED
Task attempt_201310101346_0661_m_000068_2 failed to report status for 600 seconds. Killing!
13/10/28 13:09:55 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 72% reduce 21%
13/10/28 13:10:30 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 72% reduce 22%
13/10/28 13:10:33 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 73% reduce 22%
13/10/28 13:12:21 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 74% reduce 22%
13/10/28 13:13:40 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 74% reduce 23%
13/10/28 13:14:09 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_201310101346_0661
13/10/28 13:14:09 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 31
13/10/28 13:14:09 INFO mapred.JobClient:   File System Counters
13/10/28 13:14:09 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE: Number of bytes read=0
13/10/28 13:14:09 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE: Number of bytes written=542433323
13/10/28 13:14:09 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE: Number of read operations=0
13/10/28 13:14:09 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE: Number of large read operations=0
13/10/28 13:14:09 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE: Number of write operations=0
13/10/28 13:14:09 INFO mapred.JobClient:     HDFS: Number of bytes read=316452240
13/10/28 13:14:09 INFO mapred.JobClient:     HDFS: Number of bytes written=0
13/10/28 13:14:09 INFO mapred.JobClient:     HDFS: Number of read operations=100
13/10/28 13:14:09 INFO mapred.JobClient:     HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
13/10/28 13:14:09 INFO mapred.JobClient:     HDFS: Number of write operations=0
13/10/28 13:14:09 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Job Counters 
13/10/28 13:14:09 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Failed map tasks=1
13/10/28 13:14:09 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Launched map tasks=169
13/10/28 13:14:09 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Launched reduce tasks=1
13/10/28 13:14:09 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Data-local map tasks=23
13/10/28 13:14:09 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Rack-local map tasks=146
13/10/28 13:14:09 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=72419457
13/10/28 13:14:09 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=1194624
13/10/28 13:14:09 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all maps waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
 13/10/28 13:14:09 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all reduces waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
 13/10/28 13:14:09 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Map-Reduce Framework
13/10/28 13:14:09 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map input records=6894035
13/10/28 13:14:09 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output records=6422195
 13/10/28 13:14:09 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output bytes=2300749768
13/10/28 13:14:09 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Input split bytes=6200
13/10/28 13:14:09 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine input records=6422195
13/10/28 13:14:09 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine output records=801608
13/10/28 13:14:09 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Spilled Records=801608
13/10/28 13:14:09 INFO mapred.JobClient:     CPU time spent (ms)=48077980
13/10/28 13:14:09 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=13246660608
13/10/28 13:14:09 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=20080971776
 13/10/28 13:14:09 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total committed heap usage (bytes)=10181214208
 13/10/28 13:14:09 INFO mapred.JobClient:   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormatCounter
 13/10/28 13:14:09 INFO mapred.JobClient:     BYTES_READ=316416597
 13/10/28 13:14:09 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job Failed: NA
 Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Job failed!
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1373)
    at Mondrian8.main(Mondrian8.java:547)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:208)
```

Comment: when you say the "log" file are you talking about the output to the console or did you go look at the ACTUAL Mapper log files on the DataNodes?

Comment: I mean the log file stored under _log folder in the output folder.